# Value from select tag html won't get added to database

Tags: html, postgresql, forms, asp.net-core, razor-pages

im trying to make a reservation page in aspnet Razor pages. Im having trouble with adding values from the html to the postgresql database. When i choose an option from the select tag and click submit the Locationid and Roomid wont get added. The values just stay 0, i have no idea why. The other input tags like the Email and the Dayid does work though, they do get added to the database.
Can anyone tell me whats wrong?
Here is the html-code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email</td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="txtEmail" name="Email" class="form-control" type="email">
                                    </div>

                                <td>Date</td>
                                
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' name="Dayid">
                                            <input type='date' class="form-control" name="Dayid" />
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <td>Select location</td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select id="locations" name="Locationid">
                                            @foreach(var reservations in @Model.PopulateReservations())
                                            {                                        
                                                <option value="0">@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.LocationName)</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>                                       
                                    </div>
                                <td>Select Room</td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select id="rooms" name="Roomid">
                                            @foreach(var reservations in @Model.ShowRoom())
                                            {
                                               <option value="0">@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.RoomName)</option>
                                                 
                                            }
                                        </select>                                       
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form group">
                                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" asp-page-handler="Submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"> Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                            </tr>
                        </fieldset>
                        @Model.Info
                    </form>
```

Here is c# side for the html page:

```
namespace Project_Corona.Pages
{
    public class EmployeepageModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<EmployeepageModel> _logger;
        
        public EmployeepageModel(ILogger<EmployeepageModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public string Info { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        
        }
        public void  OnPostSubmit(ReservationModel reservation)
        {
            this.Info = string.Format("Reservation successfully saved");

            CreateReservation(reservation.Reservationid, reservation.Dayid, reservation.Roomid, reservation.Email, reservation.Locationid);
        }   

        public void CreateReservation(int Reservationid, DateTime Dayid, string Roomid, string Email, string Locationid) 
        {
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();

            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            var sql = "INSERT INTO reservation(reservationid, dayid, roomid, email, locationid) VALUES(@Reservationid, @Dayid, @Roomid, @Email, @Locationid)";
            using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("reservationid", Reservationid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dayid", Dayid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("roomid", Roomid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("locationid", Locationid);

            cmd.Prepare();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();  
        }

        public List<WorkspaceModel> PopulateReservations()
        {
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
            List<WorkspaceModel> res = new List<WorkspaceModel>();
            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            {
                string query = "Select location FROM workspaces";
                using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { LocationName = dr["location"].ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                    
                    con.Close();
                }
            }


            return res;
        }

        public List<WorkspaceModel> ShowRoom()
        {
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
            List<WorkspaceModel> res = new List<WorkspaceModel>();
            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            {
                string query = "Select room FROM workspaces";
                using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = dr["room"].ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                    
                    con.Close();
                }
            }


            return res;
        }


    }
}
```

And here is the reservationmodel, if thats necessary:

```
namespace Project_Corona.Models
{
    public class ReservationModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public int Reservationid {get; set;}
        [BindProperty]
        public DateTime Dayid {get; set;}
        [BindProperty]
        public string Roomid {get; set;}
        [BindProperty]
        public string Email {get; set;}
        [BindProperty]
        public string Locationid {get; set;}


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `Locationid` or `Roomid` in your database? Because the value in `<option>` does not change with the loop, you can add a loop variable to set the value, as this.

```
 <td>Select location</td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="locations" name="Locationid">
                @for (var i= 0; i < Model.PopulateReservations().Count(); i++)
                {
                    <option value="@(i+1)">@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.PopulateReservations()[i].LocationName)</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
```

If you cannot map `LocationName` in this way, you need to query `LocationId` from the database at the same time, and then assign it to value. Or you can assign the value as this code.

```
<select id="rooms" name="Roomid">
                @foreach (var reservations in @Model.ShowRoom())
                {
                    <option value="@reservations.RoomName">@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.RoomName)</option>
                }
            </select>
```